# Trimming a DateTime object in New-Style Formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm trying to use the new style formatting ("PyFormat") and print a general variable, it may be a string, float, bool or a `DateTime` object.
It seems fine for straight-forward formatting:

```
import datetime
"{0}".format(datetime.datetime.now())
```

However, when trying to mix in the truncation `{0:.300}`, it fails:

```
import datetime
"{0:.300}".format(datetime.datetime.now())  # returns '.300'
```

It seems to work fine for strings, floats, and virtually any objects. But it fails for `DateTime` obejcts.

How can I tackle this? Should I convert each variable to string using `str()` before? It seems like it beats the purpose of the style formatting itself...

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. You want to truncate the output to 300 characters?

Comment: Yes. It is a general-purpose formatter that I'm using for possibly very long strings.

Comment: How about `str(x)[:300]`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It works. Just doesn't seem very Pythonic to me. The format handles this magic for me. It looks like I misunderstood something, or it's a bug.

Comment: looks like the length trimmer only works with strings, it fails when numbers are used. It works with dates only after they are converted to strings using strftime()

Answer (score 0):

Everything that comes after the `:` is sent as a parameter to the object's `__format__` method. In this case, it's equivalent to calling `datetime.strftime`. That's also why it works on `str` and `float`. E.g.:

```
>>> '{0:%-%m-%d}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
'2017-12-31'
```

Your best choice is either `'{0:300}'.format(str(datetime.datetime.now()))` or simply `str(datetime.datetime.now())[:300]`.